# Code to add magento custom option to attach picassa photo

Tags: magento

Can anybody help to add a "**picassa photo**" type magento custom options, to attach **picassa photo** and want to attach that file while adding product to cart programmatically. If possible i want a thumbnail of the image in the invoice.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: I am trying to understand picassa api, not yet.